# Create a table in the header of a *.docx file

Tags: python, document, docx

I have the following working code usinf `python-docx`:

```
import docx

inp = input('inp: ')


def write_docx_header():
    document = docx.Document('Test.docx')
    section = document.sections[0]
    header = section.header
    paragraph = header.paragraphs[0]
    paragraph.text = inp + "\t" + inp + "\t" + inp
    paragraph.style = document.styles["Header"]
    document.save('Test.docx')


write_docx_header()
```

Now I want a table with three columns in the header not the three tabs, but I don't know where to start and how to do it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
    records = (
        (3, 'Spam', 'Meow'),
        (7, 'Eggs', 'Meow'),
        (4, 'Spam, spam, eggs, and spam', 'Meow')
    )    
    table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
    table.style = 'TableGrid'  # apply styling
    header_cells = table.rows[0].cells
    header_cells[0].text = 'ID'
    header_cells[1].text = 'Name'
    header_cells[2].text = 'Cat'
    for id, desc, meow in records:
        row_cells = table.add_row().cells
        row_cells[0].text = str(id)
        row_cells[1].text = desc
        row_cells[2].text = meow
    document.save('Test.docx')
```

[References.](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Table styles.](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html#table-styles-in-default-template)

Comment: looks good but it does not create a table in my *.docx document and i don't know why

Comment: @0x01_PH you mean it doesn't draw borders?

Comment: i am such an idiot. deleted the document.save() at the end of the def by mistake. sorry sorry sorry. now it works fine. thank you so much